# Why does the npm package ship with node_modules bundled?

Tags: node.js, npm

Generally when you browse a module on npm there is no `node_modules` there. It's as far as I know an anti-pattern to upload your `node_modules/` to npm. That's supposed to be created and populated by the client when they run `npm install`.

For an example of this take the popular Node.js library, [Ramda](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda).

- Open https://www.npmjs.com/package/ramda?activeTab=explore
- Notice there

  - is **NOT** a `node_modules/` directory
  - there is a `package.json` file there for the client that installs it.

Now compare that to the [upstream npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm)

- Open https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm?activeTab=explore
- Notice there

  - is a `node_modules/` directory
  - there is a `package.json` file there for the client that installs it.

Why does *just* npm ship the `node_modules/` directory?

---

Follow up question [*"How do package.json's version numbers function when bundling a node_modules/ directory for your dependencies?"*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75526299/124486)

Comment: Yep, that does @Marco. Thanks I didn't think to use the term bundled, until I rewrote the title.

Answer (score 0):

> It's as far as I know an anti-pattern to upload your node_modules/ to npm.

It's not an anti-pattern, some modules like to include their dependencies in the bundle.

I like to do that as well [with pure JS dependencies] since it kind of decouples the dependency from npm itself.

There's an option in package.json that does just that:

[`bundleDependencies`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#bundledependencies)

> This defines an array of package names that will be bundled when publishing the package.

> In cases where you need to preserve npm packages locally or have them available through a single file download, you can bundle the packages in a tarball file by specifying the package names in the bundleDependencies array and executing npm pack.